# how to place bootstrap panel column directly another column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap, I have 4 panel columns (A, B, C and D ) equal widths but different height.  A is very short and B is very long height.  I know I can display A, B and C right next to each other.  Currently, I can display it underneath A but it begins only at the area where B ends. How can I display panel column D directly underneath A?

Clarification on question on bootstrap panel column.  I can successfully do this:
[image]

but would like some guidance on how to do this with panel D:
[image]

Comment: A - This is confusing, B - Please include your code (html/css), C - Read about creating [mcve], D - Thanks

Comment: I added some images in my query.  Hope this helps clarify my question.

Comment: If you're using bootstrap 4 you should see [Card columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns)

Comment: @kakamg0 unfortunately, I'm using 3.